# How to query specific hidden folder for images in android

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I need to query a specific hidden folder created by my application and need to fetch all the images saved in that hidden folder. I am able to query that very same folder if its not hidden but when I make the folder hidden, the cursor counts returns me 0 even though images are well kept inside the folder.

```
  public static List<MediaData> getHiddenFolderData(Context context) {
    Cursor imagecursor = null;
    List<MediaData> gallerydata = new ArrayList<MediaData>();
    try {
        final String orderBy = Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
        imagecursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projectionImage,
                        Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + "='"
                                + ".HiddenFolder" + "'", null,
                        orderBy);
        System.out.println("1026  check log 1");
        if (imagecursor != null) {
            System.out.println("1026  check log 2");
            imagecursor.moveToFirst();
            int count = imagecursor.getCount();
            System.out.println("1026  check log 3 count"+" "+count);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                MediaData galData = new MediaData();
                galData.setKey_id(i);
                galData.setId(imagecursor.getString(0));
                galData.setName(imagecursor.getString(1));
                galData.setPath(imagecursor.getString(2));
                galData.setDate(imagecursor.getString(3));
                gallerydata.add(galData);
                imagecursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (imagecursor != null) {
            imagecursor.close();
        }
    }
    return gallerydata;
}
```

Another approach

```
 private void getHiddenFolderData() {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/.HiddenFolder";
    System.out.println("here is path" + " " + "Path: " + path);
    File directory = new File(path);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    System.out.println("here is size" + " " + files.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("here get file prop"+" "+files[i].getName()+" "+files[i].getPath());

    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you list the files in the directory yourself? Why asking the MediaStore to do so?

Comment: please have a look on my edited question . I have created another function in which I am fetching all the files from specified folder without using MediaStore. A problem problem that I am facing is how to get details for my MediaData bean class, details like setID & setDate . Currently I am only getting name and path of the files.